# Java Program Doesn't Return Int

Tags: java

I am attempting a program on CodeWars and one of the requirements is that the persistent() function return an int. I am having trouble forming it in a way that it always returns an int. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
public class Persist 
{
  public static int persistence(int n) 
  {
    int product = n;
    int numReiterations = 0; 

    while (length(product) != 1)
    {
      product = multiplyDigits(product);
      numReiterations++; 
    } 

    if (length(product) == 1)
      return numReiterations; 
  }

  public static int multiplyDigits(int num)
  {
    int product = 1; 

    for (int x=0; x<String.valueOf(num).length(); x++) 
    {
      char numChar = String.valueOf(num).charAt(x); 
      int numBack = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(numChar)); 
      product *= numBack; 
    }

    return product; 
  }

  public static int length(int product)
  {
    return String.valueOf(product).length(); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Add a return value if the length(product) != 1

Comment: Wouldn't I have to seriously restructure the program then?

Comment: what value you want?

Comment: You must always have a return statement outside any if/else block if the function returns something. After the if(length(product==1)) block, return -99999999 or some error code if that return shouldn't be hit during normal operation.

Comment: The program should return 'numReiterations' when the cycle - mulitply the digits in the number together, if the result's not one digit then repeat - is done

Comment: I'd drop the if check against == 1 and always return the numInterations regardless.

Comment: You don't need the `if` check before return at all. Anyway the while loop will terminate only if `length(product)==1`. So just remove the condition and return.

Comment: @Prashanth Chandra, thanks, I did that and it worked.

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't use string arithmetic at all. Also you don't need to check the length of the number again, as you know it must be `1`, you just broke out of the while loop.

If you use String processing, it is not only longer but much slower. I would also use a `long` instead of an `int` as this allows for much bigger numbers at little cost.

```
public static int persistence(long n) {
    int numReiterations = 0;

    for (long product = n; !isSingleDigit(product); product = multiplyDigits(product))
        numReiterations++;

    return numReiterations;
}

public static long multiplyDigits(long num) {
    long product = 1;
    for (; num > 0; num /= 10)
        product *= num % 10;
    return product;
}

public static boolean isSingleDigit(long n) {
    return n <= 9;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(persistence(99999999999999999L));
}
```

prints

```
3
```

Answer (score 0):

You must always have at least one return statement **outside** any if/else block if the function is supposed to return something.
Not just in Java, but any similar, strongly-typed language.

After the `if(length(product==1)) block`, `return -99999999` or some error code *if that return shouldn't be hit during normal operation*.

Answer (score 0):

Your `while` loop terminates only when `length(product)` is equal to 1. So just return `numIterations` by removing the `if` condition.